# Poor font rendering in all browsers.

Tags: windows-7, display, fonts

I've been experiencing a strange problem with one person's laptop that I maintain. The computer shows oddly formatted fonts in all browsers. I think it's one specific font family but I don't have a way to confirm this. 
I've attached screenshots from [Chrome 51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjVqf.png) and [Internet Explorer 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4VV3.png). Due to being too new to the site I can only attach two links but Firefox looks very similar to what IE looks like.

We've tried messing with Cleartype, Turned on and off the "smooth edges of screen fonts", Updated the Video Card driver for the Intel HD Graphics. I've removed KB3013455 which was rumored to have issues with fonts. Nothing has made any sort of noticable difference.

My problem is everything I find regarding fonts seems to be related to browsers, usually chrome and it's font rendering engine. This problem has shown up in all browsers, multiple websites (ebay.ca pictured), emails that use certain fonts, etc. I have a feeling it's a problem with Helvetica or one of the fonts in that family but I can't confirm. And I don't know how to correct this. I'm open to any suggestions. Last resort will be to re-install windows 7 but that's not something i'm looking forward to. Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate when this happens, but after banging my head on the desk for over a week trying to figure this out I was able to solve it about 15 minutes after posting this question.

The solution was to remove all Helvetica fonts from the computer. I did not realize that this was a commercial font, and the user had "acquired" it and installed it on her own and that font was causing issues. Based on windows telling me "Helvetica Neue Ultralight" was in use I think this font was this problem. All Helvetica fonts have been removed, and while some pages are showing slightly differently now everything is legible again. A bit more digging shows that if you don't have "Helvetica Neue" installed windows will choose a different variant of the font and display that and Helvetica Neue is a rather common font used in webpages.